# Joomla site content not loading

Tags: php, joomla-1.6

I recently shifted Joomla 1.6 site from one server to another. The site template is showing, but the articles and components are not loading.

I tried the SEO friendly URL option, but turning it on and off didn't work or change the URL. Also now it's running on a newer version of PHP 5.5, I also checked for php errors after setting the display errors to maximum which then showed two errors, one of which had a deprecated `preg_replace` function which I replaced with `preg_replace_callback` and second was

> Declaration of JCacheStorage::get() should be compatible with JObject::get($property, $default = NULL)

Comment: By staying on Joomla 1.6 and providing a link to your site, you're leaving yourself and your users highly vulnerable. If you don't update to Joomla 3.4.6 in the next few hours, I'll flag this question to a moderator to have it removed for your own safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found out that the issue was with the jdoc in templates index file and it was not rendering due to "imagecreatetruecolor" function and incorrect path to a file. After installing php-gd extension and correcting the path, the site content is now loading.

The file was included using require_once which was inside an div tag block which had display property set to none and that's why the errors where not showing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Joomla 1.6 was only intended as a short term release and you should probably update to Joomla 3.x to keep your website secure. See https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/upgrade-joomla-16-to-25/ for instructions on upgrading to Joomla 2.5. The update from 2.5 to 3.x is relatively simple.

Here are a couple of things to try:

1. If you can choose your PHP version in cPanel or similar, try changing to PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 to see if that helps.
2. Rename `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.old` or similar and copy the default `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` at least temporarily to see if that helps. If it does, check to see what changes have been made in `.htaccess.old` as they may not suit the new hosting environment.

It probably isn't causing the issue, but check the tmp and logs paths are correct in Global Configuration.

Comment: Tried updating but too many errors popped up, cannot change the php version, tried htaccess too, also checked the paths of both tmp and log folders

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.5 is very unlikely to work for a J1.6 installation and corresponding template for that version.

Either:

1. **Change your PHP version** to the version you were using on the previous server.
2. OR better yet, keep using PHP 5.5 and **upgrade your installation to J3 and update your template**.

Guaranteed that will solve your issues

Comment: Changed to php 5.3 but still the content is not loading, updating J1.6 to J2.5 is giving me a lot of erros

Comment: Your template is most likely where the errors would be coming from. You are half way there - better to update your template for J3 and complete the move to the latest version of Joomla. To install J3 try the Joomla Update menu (clear cache and refresh) or just upload the latest J3 version through the extension manager. Then try to run J3 on PHP 5.5.

Comment: Updating gives a lot of error, installed extension might not work with J3. Some of the articles are loading but as plain text without the template

Comment: Yes I omitted to mention that any 3rd party extensions need to be updated as CMS platforms are always progressing on the back of updated PHP versions.